# When is it OK to list publications from a previous institution

Tags: publications, citations

I've published a few articles on some work I did at a previous research institute. I've recently moved to a new research institute and have continued much of the same work. The new institute wants to put up a list of publications to demonstrate the skills and expertise of their current staff there and would like to link to some of my old publications, without altering anything in them.

Now I can surely see the value in showcasing "this is what our people can do" and I don't see any harm in it since it will still clearly show the institute where the work was originally done, and is inline with the current institutions work, but it might be seen as padding an unfair attributions.

Is this a matter of opinion or are there clear guidelines here?

Comment: In my experience, employers/institutions vary in their policy whether they prefer to list "work that was done here" or "work/experise our employees have" - which is both fine. So I'd say it's more a matter of your employer's opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand the question correctly. What does it mean to "put up a list of publications"? What precisely is going to happen with that list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Always.  If you wrote it, you should list it.  The list of publications associated with each member of the staff explains what they bring to the organization. Collectively, it gives a picture of the talent they've assembled.   But anyone reading these lists has to know people move around and that if, for example, you had a best paper in your previous position, it's still a best paper and of course you'll list it -- and that you'll list any other publications as well.  They'll expect you to list them all.

I think most people will take for granted that some of your publications probably happened elsewhere.  If they click the link to read your paper and it recites your differing association at the time, they will know for sure that it did.